# Convert numbers in Google Sheets to Text / Words

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, substitution

Example:

| value | desired output |
| --- | --- |
| 300 | Three Hundred |
| 300.50 | Three Hundred and 50 cents |

I can't find a way to do this in Google Sheets, and I am not savvy enough to build anything.

Answer (score 12):

This website
https://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/1015010-convert-a-numeric-value-to-words-without-vba.html

Does show an Excel formula that can do this. I just tested in Google Sheets and this also works.

The formula is

```
=IF(OR(LEN(FLOOR(E3,1))>=13,FLOOR(E3,1)<=0),"Out of range",PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),1,1)+1,"","one hundred ","two hundred ","three hundred ","four hundred ","five hundred ","six hundred ","seven hundred ","eight hundred ","nine hundred "),CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),2,1)+1,"",CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),3,1)+1,"ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"),"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"),IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),2,1))>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),3,1)+1,"","-one","-two","-three","-four","-five","-six","-seven","-eight","-nine"),IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),2,1))=0,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),3,1)+1,"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"),"")),IF(E3>=10^9," billion ",""),CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),4,1)+1,"","one hundred ","two hundred ","three hundred ","four hundred ","five hundred ","six hundred ","seven hundred ","eight hundred ","nine hundred "),CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),5,1)+1,"",CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),6,1)+1,"ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"),"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"),IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),5,1))>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),6,1)+1,"","-one","-two","-three","-four","-five","-six","-seven","-eight","-nine"),IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),5,1))=0,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),6,1)+1,"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"),"")),IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),4,3))>0," million ",""),CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),7,1)+1,"","one hundred ","two hundred ","three hundred ","four hundred ","five hundred ","six hundred ","seven hundred ","eight hundred ","nine hundred "),CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),8,1)+1,"",CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),9,1)+1,"ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"),"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"),IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),8,1))>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),9,1)+1,"","-one","-two","-three","-four","-five","-six","-seven","-eight","-nine"),IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),8,1))=0,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),9,1)+1,"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"),"")),IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),7,3))," thousand ",""),CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),10,1)+1,"","one hundred ","two hundred ","three hundred ","four hundred ","five hundred ","six hundred ","seven hundred ","eight hundred ","nine hundred "),CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),11,1)+1,"",CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),12,1)+1,"ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"),"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"),IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),11,1))>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),12,1)+1,"","-one","-two","-three","-four","-five","-six","-seven","-eight","-nine"),IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),11,1))=0,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(E3),REPT(0,12)),12,1)+1,"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"),""))),"  "," ")&IF(FLOOR(E3,1)>1," dollars"," dollar")))
```

Answer (score 6):

**little tweaks here and there of [dominic's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9099497/dominic) answer to suit your needs exactly as you desire:**

```
=REGEXREPLACE(IF(OR(LEN(FLOOR(A1,1))>=13,FLOOR(A1,1)<=0),"Out of range",
 PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),1,1)+1,"","one hundred ","two hundred ","three hundred ","four hundred ","five hundred ","six hundred ","seven hundred ","eight hundred ","nine hundred "),
 CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),2,1)+1,"",CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),3,1)+1,"ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"),"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"),
 IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),2,1))>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),3,1)+1,"","-one","-two","-three","-four","-five","-six","-seven","-eight","-nine"),
 IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),2,1))=0,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),3,1)+1,"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"),"")),
 IF(A1>=10^9," billion ",""),
 CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),4,1)+1,"","one hundred ","two hundred ","three hundred ","four hundred ","five hundred ","six hundred ","seven hundred ","eight hundred ","nine hundred "),
 CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),5,1)+1,"",CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),6,1)+1,"ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"),"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"),
 IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),5,1))>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),6,1)+1,"","-one","-two","-three","-four","-five","-six","-seven","-eight","-nine"),
 IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),5,1))=0,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),6,1)+1,"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"),"")),
 IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),4,3))>0," million ",""),CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),7,1)+1,"","one hundred ","two hundred ","three hundred ","four hundred ","five hundred ","six hundred ","seven hundred ","eight hundred ","nine hundred "),
 CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),8,1)+1,"",CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),9,1)+1,"ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"),"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"),
 IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),8,1))>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),9,1)+1,"","-one","-two","-three","-four","-five","-six","-seven","-eight","-nine"),
 IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),8,1))=0,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),9,1)+1,"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"),"")),
 IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),7,3))," thousand ",""),CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),10,1)+1,"","one hundred ","two hundred ","three hundred ","four hundred ","five hundred ","six hundred ","seven hundred ","eight hundred ","nine hundred "),
 CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),11,1)+1,"",CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),12,1)+1,"ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"),"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"),
 IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1), 
 REPT(0,12)),11,1))>1,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),12,1)+1,"","-one","-two","-three","-four","-five","-six","-seven","-eight","-nine"),
 IF(VALUE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),11,1))=0,CHOOSE(MID(TEXT(INT(A1),
 REPT(0,12)),12,1)+1,"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"),""))),"  "," "))&
 IF(IFERROR(QUERY({A1},"where Col1 Contains '.'"),)<>"",
 " and "&REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1), "\.(.+)")&" cents", )),"  ", " ")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Your edit outputs the decimal places as well, right?

Comment: @Khan yes indeed

Answer (score 3):

Since this is specifically for Google Sheet, you can use this

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN(", ",QUERY(IMPORTDATA("https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/conversions/numberstowords.php?number=" & A1 & "&format=words&letter_case=lowercase&action=solve"),"where Col1 contains '<div id=""answer""><br>'")),">([^<]+)")
```

where A1 is the number you want to convert

Credit: [spell number formulae or number to words](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4329181?hl=en). There are also many alternative solutions in that link, for example here's a way that uses array formula

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",if(len(int(A2:A))<13,"",if(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-12),3)+0>99,choose(left(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-12),3))+0,"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine")&" hundred ",)&if(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-12),3),2)*1>19,choose(left(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-12),3),2))-1,"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety")&choose(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-12),3))+1,""," one"," two"," three"," four"," five"," six"," seven"," eight"," nine"),choose(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-12),3),2)+1,"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"))&" trillion")&" "&if(len(int(A2:A))<10,"",if(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-9),3)+0>99,choose(left(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-9),3))+0,"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine")&" hundred ",)&if(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-9),3),2)*1>19,choose(left(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-9),3),2))-1,"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety")&choose(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-9),3))+1,""," one"," two"," three"," four"," five"," six"," seven"," eight"," nine"),choose(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-9),3),2)+1,"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"))&" billion")&" "&if(len(int(A2:A))<7,"",if(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-6),3)+0>99,choose(left(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-6),3))+0,"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine")&" hundred ",)&if(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-6),3),2)*1>19,choose(left(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-6),3),2))-1,"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety")&choose(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-6),3))+1,""," one"," two"," three"," four"," five"," six"," seven"," eight"," nine"),choose(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-6),3),2)+1,"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"))&" million")&" "&if(len(int(A2:A))<4,"",if(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-3),3)+0>99,choose(left(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-3),3))+0,"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine")&" hundred ",)&if(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-3),3),2)*1>19,choose(left(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-3),3),2))-1,"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety")&choose(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-3),3))+1,""," one"," two"," three"," four"," five"," six"," seven"," eight"," nine"),choose(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-3),3),2)+1,"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"))&" thousand")&" "&if(len(int(A2:A))<1,"",if(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-0),3)+0>99,choose(left(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-0),3))+0,"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine")&" hundred ",)&if(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-0),3),2)*1>19,choose(left(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-0),3),2))-1,"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety")&choose(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-0),3))+1,""," one"," two"," three"," four"," five"," six"," seven"," eight"," nine"),choose(right(right(left(int(A2:A),len(int(A2:A))-0),3),2)+1,"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen")))&if(int(A2:A)=0,"0 dollar",if(int(A2:A)<2," dollar"," dollars"))&iferror(" and "&if(round(mod(A2:A,1)*100,2)>19,choose(left(mod(A2:A,1)*100)-1,"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety")&choose(right(round(mod(A2:A,1)*100,2))+1,""," one"," two"," three"," four"," five"," six"," seven"," eight"," nine"),choose(round(mod(A2:A,1)*100,2)+1,"no","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen"))&" cents")))
```

The output is

```
300         three hundred  dollars and no cents
300.5       three hundred  dollars and fifty cents
```

[image: Array formula for number conversion example]

Just change the `A2:A` in the array formula to the correct position if your numbers are in a different position

---

Another way is to clone the below 2 already-made sheets by selecting *File > Make a copy* and then use

- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jQkM5kqvaG-T0M1nqrZO5Wc9A9yjdKeAI2hFCjWa9sA/edit?usp=sharing
- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13f7ITHSPIy8CWyhkDpGlqJL0EzFjBrMEAnEm08V7ytg/edit?usp=sharing

Credit: [Amount or Numbers to Words Converter Using Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/amount-or-numbers-to-words-converter-using-google-sheets/). The author also introduced newer versions that need only a single sheet. If you want to use those [clone it from here](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqmKElah2yJWCT-8ZJNCLutpjRwfQken4MkH0t25nlY/copy&followup=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqmKElah2yJWCT-8ZJNCLutpjRwfQken4MkH0t25nlY/copy&ltmpl=sheets)

[image: Number to word converter]

Answer (score 2):

You can try [the Numbertext Add-on](https://gsuite.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/numbertext/505819167361?hl=en)

```
=NUMBERTEXT("EUR 25") => twenty-five euro

=MONEYTEXT(25,"EUR") => twenty-five euro
```

Answer (score 0):

- make a copy of this file: **[converter](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqmKElah2yJWCT-8ZJNCLutpjRwfQken4MkH0t25nlY/copy)**
- and then either add these two sheets into your spreadsheet or use `IMPORTRANGE` to import value over in **F6** and another `IMPORTRANGE` to import back the converted value from **B11**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to convert you currency in words:

```js
function convertToWords(input) {

  var a, b, c, d, e, output, outputA, outputB, outputC, outputD, outputE;

  var ones = ['', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

  if (input === 0) { // Zero

    output = "Rupees zero";

  } else if (input == 1) { // One

    output = "Rupee one only";

  } else { // More than one

    // Tens
    a = input % 100;
    outputA = oneToHundred_(a);

    // Hundreds
    b = Math.floor((input % 1000) / 100);
    if (b > 0 && b < 10) {
      outputB = ones[b];
    }

    // Thousands
    c = (Math.floor(input / 1000)) % 100;
    outputC = oneToHundred_(c);

    // Lakh
    d = (Math.floor(input / 100000)) % 100;
    outputD = oneToHundred_(d);

    // Crore
    e = (Math.floor(input / 10000000)) % 100;
    outputE = oneToHundred_(e);

    // Make string
    output = "Rupees";

    if (e > 0) {
      output = output + " " + outputE + " crore";
    }

    if (d > 0) {
      output = output + " " + outputD + " lakh";
    }

    if (c > 0) {
      output = output + " " + outputC + " thousand";
    }

    if (b > 0) {
      output = output + " " + outputB + " hundred";
    }

    if (input > 100 && a > 0) {
      output = output + " and";
    }

    if (a > 0) {
      output = output + " " + outputA;
    }

    output = output + " only";
  }

  return output;

}

function oneToHundred_(num) {

  var outNum;

  var ones = ['', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

  var teens = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];

  var tens = ['', '', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];

  if (num > 0 && num < 10) { // 1 to 9

    outNum = ones[num]; // ones

  } else if (num > 9 && num < 20) { // 10 to 19

    outNum = teens[(num % 10)]; // teens

  } else if (num > 19 && num < 100) { // 20 to 100

    outNum = tens[Math.floor(num / 10)]; // tens

    if (num % 10 > 0) {

      outNum = outNum + " " + ones[num % 10]; // tens + ones

    }

  }

  return outNum;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

The proposed solution shows the wrong result in some cases. More tests are needed.

---

Please try:

`=GOOGLETRANSLATE(BAHTTEXT(7245.01),"th","en")`

The result is

> Seven thousand two hundred forty five baht, one satang

[image]

Then use regex or text function to get rid/replace this:

- baht → to $ or currency
- satang → to cents or other.

Here's the list of language codes for translation:

https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

Comment: For `124451` I get *One hundred thousand, twenty, four thousand four hundred, fifty-eleven.* which is wrong.

Comment: @Markus von Broady
thanks for test, will edit my answer when I'll have some general logic of the error, now I guess it is a bug as `BAHTTEXT` as currently a documented function